# How to make dr.eggman mustache?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, hair

[image]

I am trying to make a the mustache in the picture above but can’t make the same thing. So far I have tried modeling the mustache but there is no hair and it’s just a flat mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with hair cards (= polygons with a few hairs mapped to them and a lot of transparency), you can find information about that here:
http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/HairTechnique
This here shows the general (program independent) workflow, for the haird on top of the head, but you should be able to adapt it:
[tutorial from Athey Moravetz @ deviantart](https://orig09.deviantart.net/ba83/f/2012/012/1/1/polygon_hair_tutorial___3dsmax_by_athey-d4m4pma.jpg)

You could also use the inbuilt hair system, depending on your hardware specs:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/physics/particles/hair/index.html

Comment: yes the first method is a nice way, perhaps you should explain in few words and screenshots

Comment: is this better? :)

Comment: Could you do this in blender?

Comment: is this a gerneral question as in: 
"is this workflow possible in blender?" 
or
are you asking me to do these images in blender?

short answers: yes and no. :)

Comment: yes, that's fine   ;)

Comment: I’m asking if this is possible in blender

Comment: This tutorial demonstrates how to apply alpha mapped textures (/materials) to a mesh:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka5k-ahO4Zo

If you want to see the transparency in the viewport, select the mesh with the material, in the "properties" pane switch to the "material" tab and scroll down to the "settings" section. change the alpha value of the viewport color to 0

Now you can duplicate your plane to your hearts content, until you have the beard replicated (I would not use flat planes, but rather subdivide them once and give them some depth, so they do not vanish when viewed from the side)

Comment: I downvoted this answer for a few reasons, this basically seems like a blatant rip off of someone else's tutorial. Although the basic principles may apply, it is not made in Blender, nor does it attempt to explain any differences in worflow. It is also just one big image with text, which is great for editing and can't be easily indexed, so it may not show up in future searches

Answer (score 1):

You can use hair particles.

Add a particle system and set it to hair. Choose a higher number for *segments* (e.g. 10).
Go to *Particle Edit* mode. Select some tips and scale them towards their center to create a pointy end segment. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad+</kbd> select additional segments of the same strands and comb, smooth or cut them.

[image: hair editing]

Unwrap the emitter object and use Noise Textures to create color variations in the material.

[image: node setup]

Use child particles, if the hair is not dense enough.

[image]