# Game-ready hair mesh technique like Zbrush's imm brushes or better

Tags: modeling, texturing, unity, hair

I wanted to figure out the best approach for game-ready hair that would likely be running in Unity as its game engine. I've found that Zbrush has imm brush/ hair strips and cards as a popular method. 
1. How would this process be done in Blender or a technique to get results similar?
2. Would it take around the same time or would it be faster/easier just to invest in Zbrush? 
3. If the substitute technique can't achieve effects as good as this hair strip method, what should I do instead with Blender?

With the game aspect in mind, I do want it to be able to be ran in a game engine of course, with performance generally in mind.

[image: Example of Zbrush hair card method]

[image: An example of hair strips in an AAA game]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120234/how-to-make-dr-eggman-mustache/120235#120235

Comment: I don't think the particle system's results looks particularly great in my opinion. In addition, although it does seem like a practical/more expedient solution; it may look good enough for another person's purposes. For me, I'd prefer something else. Thank you for the insightful post, Duarte.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not try it but am thinking about buying the hair tool add-on. It looks like the results are very convincing.

https://bartoszstyperek.wordpress.com/2017/07/29/hair-tool-blender-addon/

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is the best solution for hair cards, huh? I've actually looked a lot into it but was hoping that there were other solutions perhaps. In any case, it seems like it's either this for 33$ or Zbrush for how much that might be at the time of writing this. So I'll go ahead and bite the bullet and get the addon. If I'm unsatisfied, I think I'll just get Zbrush to make hair cards less of a hassle. If anyone has a better hair solution for Blender, go ahead and let us know, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I want  to put this down for anyone who may read this answer for future reference. This was a breakthrough for me, and I hope it may be one for anyone who had similar problems to me.

If you

1. Don't want to pay money for the hair tool addon,
2. Don't want to pay money for Zbrush,
3. Don't want to use a particle-based hair system for Blender,
4. Don't want as limited control over hair strands in Zbrush,
5. Or if you just want to stay in Blender,

You may want to consider this following technique/addon. It's called **Bevel Curve Tools**, and it allows Blender users to use a hair-strip technique similar to Zbrush's imm brushes method while potentially being even **better**.

In addition to being free, this is supposedly better than Zbrush for controlling polycount for hair strips, easier to control tapering, generally less restricted than Zbrush's method. You can even duplicate a hair strand you may have made with its own beveling, which means you can easily manipulate it to add variation and change it to your liking. I'll be vague here since the video link below elaborates on it in much more detail if you're really interested.

For further details, please consider checking out this Youtube video on how to use these addon. And of course, free downloads to the addons themselves are both on the video's description and will be at the bottom of this post in case you are confident with learning the tool on your own.

Good luck.

[Github Bevel Curve Tools Download](https://github.com/ucupumar/bevel-curve-tools)

[Github 2 Blender Sculpt Tools (This is for extra features for Bevel Curve Tools, download this if you think you need it.)](https://github.com/MadMinstrel/blender-sculpt-tools)

[How to use Bevel Curve Tools (Youtube Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2EY4Lr5TXw)